# ListView How to get items not shown?

Tags: android, listview

As it already known in the knowledge base,

```
listView.getChildAt()
```

will return null object when the item is not shown.So I tried to use

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(...)
```

The problem seems that the content I get in this way will not change dynamically.I have a TextView with hint,after entering text and confirming, I can only get the hint while the text is empty. Please help me in finding out how to get the content if the item is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using a EditText, not a TextView.

You should notice that when you call this:

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null)
```

It often returns a new view, because convertView == null. So you got a new EditText without filling the text user entered (text is empty).

I do not understand why you want to get the content of an invisible item in ListView. So it quite hard to suggest a solution for this problem.

In normal case, you should keep the content of View (such as input characters in an EditText) in your data list. With EditText, you can use TextWatcher to monitor the change of user input, then store to respective data item. You can easily get it from a List.

Comment: I meant that when a list item is out of the screen,how to get the data inside.

Comment: Yeah, now I understood your problem. You know ListView uses recycle mechanism for items. It means each item after scroll out of screen will be reused to render an other which scroll into screen. All of data of old item will be replaced by new data. So you can not get the old content of an EditText if you did not save it before. Let try the solution in my above answer: using TextWatcher and save the text in a List.